# Convert time from a format to an int in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I can't seem to figure this out. I have some rows with time in the format 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss) and i need to calculate the total time it takes for a task.
I am unable to sum this data. Can someone advise on a way to convert this to a format i can sum or a method to calculate the total time for the task. 
Thanks for any assistance. This is in an Oracle DB.

Comment: What's the data type of the time column? Is it a *varchar* or *date* column?

Comment: DATATYPE is VARCHAR2

Answer (score 1):

Convert your time string to a date and subtract the equivalent date at midnight to give you an number as a fraction of a day. You can then sum this number and convert it to an interval:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
  SELECT '01:23:45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12:34:56' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '23:45:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
         SUM( TO_DATE( value, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS' ) ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS total_time_taken
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

```
| TOTAL_TIME_TAKEN              |
| :---------------------------- |
| +000000001 13:43:41.000000000 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a76ada40483a344a577795a69652fa4a)*

---

**Update** including durations longer than `23:59:59`.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
  SELECT '1:23:45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12:34:56' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '23:45:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '48:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
         SUM(
           DATE '1970-01-01'
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( value, 1, HM - 1 ), 'HOUR' )
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( value, HM + 1, MS - HM - 1 ), 'MINUTE' )
           + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( value, MS + 1 ), 'SECOND' )
           - DATE '1970-01-01'
         ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS total_time
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( value, ':', 1, 1 ) AS HM,
         INSTR( value, ':', 1, 2 ) AS MS
  FROM   test_data
);
```

**Output**:

```
| TOTAL_TIME                    |
| :---------------------------- |
| +000000003 13:43:41.000000000 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=58b2f7ee72150700619d3b2c2e4524a0)*

---

Even better would be if you changed your table to hold the durations as intervals rather than as strings then everything becomes much simpler:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
  SELECT INTERVAL  '1:23:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '12:34:56' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '23:45:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT INTERVAL '48:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(
         SUM( DATE '1970-01-01' + value - DATE '1970-01-01' ),
         'DAY'
       ) AS total_time
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

```
| TOTAL_TIME                    |
| :---------------------------- |
| +000000003 13:43:41.000000000 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c002fdcdda63853f98a50f841748c130)*

Comment: The values aren't a clock time but time taken. So if one task took 48 hours 12 minutes and 23 seconds. Ideally i would like a way to get the hours and minutes in a format i could sum them with.

Comment: @Outside_the_box Updated for durations longer than 24 hours.